# How do I change my foreign key into names?

Tags: angularjs

I have this code in the controller

```
      ScheduledInteractions.notComplete({},function(response)
      {$scope.pendingContacts=response}
      );
```

I have this on my service:

```
      app.factory('ScheduledInteractions', function ($resource) 
      {
       return $resource('/api/ScheduledInteractions/:id', {}, {
       show: { method: 'GET',  params: {id: '@id'} , isArray: false},
       update: { method: 'PUT', params: {id: '@id'} },        
       findLead: { url:'/api/ScheduledInteractions?filter={"where":{"leadId"::id}}', method: 'GET',  params: {id: '@id'} , isArray: true},        
       notComplete: { url:'/api/ScheduledInteractions?filter={"where":{"isCompleted":"false"}}', method: 'GET', isArray: true},        
       delete: { method: 'DELETE', params: {id: '@id'} }        
         })
      });
```

It will return data with customer ids. In my html i have something like

```
      <tr ng-repeat="p in pendingContacts"><td> {{p.leadId}}</td><td> {{p.notes}}</td></tr>
```

What is the best way of converting the id's into names from the lead table?

edit: sample response

> createdAt: "2015-06-28T16:27:11.309Z, "date:
>   "2015-06-10T04:00:00.000Z", id: 22, isCompleted: false ,isDeleted:
>   false, **leadId: 545**, notes: "need to confirm", type: "email",
>   updatedAt: "2015-06-28T16:27:11.309Z", userId: 17

Comment: How do we guess the response? can you show a sample of response please?

Comment: Won't you have to *return* the name in a response?  Either return in as part of the original response or expose an api to get the name, right?